# Spring Boot doesn't start Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

My Spring Boot application doesn't start Tomcat server when I run it in Eclipse using Spring Tool Suite. In youtube walkthrough it was show like it should work automaticly after adding tomcat boot dependency, also according to page tutorials I don't see any mistake. What's wrong?

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>wymysl2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>wymysl2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 <tomcat.version>8.0.15</tomcat.version>



    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.37</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Console output :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.7.RELEASE)

2015-11-04 19:29:55.718  INFO 5812 --- [           main] regularmikey.wymysl.Wymysl2Application   : Starting Wymysl2Application on Michal-k with PID 5812 (E:\workspace\wymysl2\target\classes started by Michal in E:\workspace\wymysl2)
2015-11-04 19:29:55.778  INFO 5812 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@13e16fd: startup date [Wed Nov 04 19:29:55 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-11-04 19:29:57.370  INFO 5812 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-11-04 19:29:57.405  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2015-11-04 19:29:57.520  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2015-11-04 19:29:57.522  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-11-04 19:29:57.524  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-11-04 19:29:57.852  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-11-04 19:29:58.647  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2015-11-04 19:29:58.841  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-11-04 19:29:59.283  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists person
Hibernate: create table person (id_per integer not null auto_increment, additional varchar(255), city varchar(255), contact_email varchar(255), country varchar(255), email varchar(255), gender varchar(255), name varchar(255), password varchar(255), surname varchar(255), primary key (id_per))
2015-11-04 19:29:59.556  INFO 5812 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2015-11-04 19:30:00.176  INFO 5812 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2015-11-04 19:30:00.200  INFO 5812 --- [           main] regularmikey.wymysl.Wymysl2Application   : Started Wymysl2Application in 4.741 seconds (JVM running for 5.477)
2015-11-04 19:30:00.201  INFO 5812 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@13e16fd: startup date [Wed Nov 04 19:29:55 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-11-04 19:30:00.202  INFO 5812 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2015-11-04 19:30:00.204  INFO 5812 --- [       Thread-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2015-11-04 19:30:00.204  INFO 5812 --- [       Thread-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists person
2015-11-04 19:30:00.293  INFO 5812 --- [       Thread-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Answer (score 3):

In the dependency for the Web starter:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

you restricted the starter to `test` scope. Drop that tag, and it should start as expected.

Comment: This should be directly below the `<parent></parent>` section.